# Importing a large dataset into MySQL using Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm developing a dashboard using Yii2. The data is held in a remote `SQL` Server database and I'm copying it into a local `MySQL` database. The data is constantly updated with the addition of new rows. I need to update the local version at least once a day. There are currently about 1.5 million lines in the relevant table through each row through each row doesn't contain much data.

In the short term, I have no control over the structure of the remote table. It has no primary key set and the rows aren't time-stamped either so (I think) I have no way of knowing at the time of each update which rows are new and which ones already existed.

My approach is every 24 hours to take a complete copy of the remote table. The problem is that PHP runs out of memory when I do this. I found the Yii2 `yii\db\Query->batch()` function (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#batch()-detail) which looked like it should do the job but I'm not sure how to use it and when I've tried so far, it runs out of memory as well.

What I've got so far looks like this -

```
foreach ($query->batch(1000) as $rows) {
    do some stuff
}
```

So I suppose I have two questions -

1. Is the batch() function the right thing to use.
2. How should I be using it if the above doesn't work?

Comment: How do you access the data held in this "remote SQL Server database". You say you "have no control over the structure of the remote table", by what means to you access the data, via an API?

Comment: I access the remote data via the Yii DAO connection for SQL Server - [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html) but I have only read access to this database and don't control it.

Comment: OK, I will start with a basic answer...

Comment: I have provided an answer - if this helps, please remember to upvote my answer and mark/tick it as the "accepted answer". Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm the following  `PHP version`, `PDO version`, `PDO settings` about emulating prepared statements?

Comment: On my local development machine: PHP - 5.5.6. I'm not sure how to find info on the PDO version or the PDO settings. Can't see anything in phpinfo about this.

Comment: ok leave it can you try to set the buffering to false on runtime like this before the query and then start the batch `Yii::$app->db->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,false)`

Comment: Many thanks, that seems to work. Can you explain at all how it works because that constant looks like it applies to MySQL PDO, not MSSQL?

Comment: You are welcome @GordonCowtan i added an answer for references and details please select it if it helped you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
Yii::$app->db->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,false)
```

before the query and then start the batch you, can use `setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false)` for `batch()` and after that return back attribute to `true` for other cases.

According to the DOCS

> When working with large amounts of data, methods such as
>   [[yii\db\Query::all()]] are not suitable because they require loading
>   the whole query result into the client's memory. To solve this issue
>   Yii provides batch query support. The server holds the query result,
>   and the client uses a cursor to iterate over the result set one batch
>   at a time.

Major Reasons as from [**`GITHUB`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9269#issuecomment-250739252)

> As a note: this will happen all the time on the default install of
>   `PHP7` now due to how `mysqlnd` now works by adding the result set's
>   memory usage to the process's own:
>   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php
>
> When using `libmysqlclient` as library PHP's memory limit won't count the memory used for result sets unless the data is fetched into
>   PHP variables. With `mysqlnd` the memory accounted for will include the
>   full result set.
>
> And `mysqlnd` is the recommended lib for the `PDO` extension now, while
>   `libmysqlclient` is now "not recommended"

A better alternative than the workaround provided above is to use unbuffered connection to the databases as in the function provided by [**`IHIPOP@Github`**](https://github.com/ihipop), see the full [**`ISSUE`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8420#issuecomment-301423833) here for details